# TFS - Move tasks between Work Items

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

As a previous result of a bad TFS project management, several tasks has been created in the wrong work item. Now I need to move several tasks to different work items. Is there an easy way to do it?

So far, I have to edit each task, remove the previos link to primary element and create a new one, but this is taking a lot of my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the easiest way to do it would be from Excel. Create a Tree-based query that shows everything, then move the child records in Excel using simple cut and insert cut cells. Excel will then allow you to publish the new structure in one go.

If you need to move items up to a higher or lower level, place the Title Field in the column representing the level.

[See this little video I captured to show how it is done.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86-8cb4LhS8&hd=1)

Comment: For the record, if one need to change a simple field can use the Team Foundation Server Power Tools workitem command, which do not support editing links. Other viable alternative is using the Object Model from Powershell.

Comment: Web Access also has a nice feature to bulk update work item fields from the query window. Also can't update relations.

Answer (score 1):

MS Project is extremely good with modifying hierarchies of work items. The steps are exactly the same as setting it up in Excel, but project inherently handles parent/child relationships, giving them a drag-and-drop interaction.

jessehouwing's Excel answer will be easier if you have never worked with project before.

**Updated** jesshouwing's comments are correct. Especially about the shivers.

Comment: Or when you are using a template that is not enabled for MsProject integration :). I tend to forget about Project, since it always brings shivers to my spine. But you're right, for this work, it would probably be great too!

Comment: Just tried it myself, but I find Excel easier. That drag and drop in Project isn't as intuitive as one might like and it's easy to accidentally push all kinds of scheduling information and overwrite the fields associated with that.